# Resize pdf pages in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am using python to crop pdf pages.
Everything works fine, but how do I change the page size(width)?

This is my crop code:

```
input = PdfFileReader(file('my.pdf', 'rb'))
p = input.getPage(1)
(w, h) = p.mediaBox.upperRight
p.mediaBox.upperRight = (w/4, h)
output.addPage(p)
```

When I crop pages, I need to resize them as well, how can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

This answer is really long overdue, and maybe the older versions of PyPDF2 didn't have this functionality, but its actually quite simple with version 1.26.0

```
import PyPDF2

pdf = "YOUR PDF FILE PATH.pdf"

pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf)
page0 = pdf.getPage(0)
page0.scaleBy(0.5)  # float representing scale factor - this happens in-place
writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()  # create a writer to save the updated results
writer.addPage(page0)
with open("YOUR OUTPUT PDF FILE PATH.pdf", "wb+") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

Comment: How can I get into landscape mode?

Comment: you can use the rotateClockwise method of the pdf page.

Comment: Will it change character coordinates also?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to scale the image after you crop it? You can use `p.scale(factor_x, factor_y)` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also apply scaling, rotation or translation directly in the merge function call, by using the functions:

- mergePage()
- mergeRotatedPage()
- mergeRotatedScaledPage()
- mergeRotatedScaledTranslatedPage()
- mergeScaledPage()
- mergeScaledTranslatedPage()
- mergeTransformedPage()
- mergeTranslatedPage()

Or use addTransformation() on a page object.

Comment: with what package?

Answer (score 0):

Ahsin Shabbir's answer works perfectly for PyPDF2, however as of October 2023 that module is deprecated and pypdf has returned to its original name. Here's a version of their answer, updated for pypdf v3.8.0:

```
import pypdf
pdf_path = r'YOUR_FILE_PATH\YOUR_FILE_NAME.PDF'
output_path = r'OUTPUT_FILE_PATH\OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.PDF'
pdf = pypdf.PdfReader(pdf_path)
writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()
page0 = pdf.pages[0]
# scale_by(0.71) reduces from e.g. A4 to A5. scale_by(0.5) reduces from A4 to A6
page0.scale_by(0.71)
writer.add_page(page0)
with open(output_path, "wb+") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this. Python3.7

```
def pdf_scale_page(page: 'PageObject', size: float = 297)->None:
    """Scale page to specified size mm"""
    (w, h) = page.mediabox[2:]
    #  Units of measurement are not "points". The units of measurement are user defined and default to 1/72 inch. See section 4.2.1 Coordinate spaces of the PDF specification.
    # If we have a page width of 297 mm and at points 1 inch = 25.4 mm
    pmm = (1/72*25.4)
    ks = size / (max((w, h)) * pmm)
    page.scale_by(ks)
```